# Custom Convention for Automapper. Mapping source.Children to ouput.ChildrenIds

Tags: .net, automapper

I know Automapper will automatically map `source.Child.Id` to `destination.ChildId` using a 'built-in' convention. Is there any way to achieve something similar between `source.Children` and `destination.ChildrenIds`?

ATM I just use the following mapping for each `destination.SomeCollectionPropertyIds` property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForMember(d => d.ChildrenIds, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Children.Select(c => c.Id).ToList()))
```

, which works of course, but I wonder if Automapper could do that automatically (using a custom Convention), so that I don't have to explicitly declare that every time.